# Simulate slow connection between two ubuntu server machines

Tags: ubuntu, networking, tcp, linux-networking, bandwidth

I want to simulate the following scenario: given that I have 4 ubuntu server machines A,B,C and D. I want to reduce the network bandwidth by 20% between machine A and machine C and 10% between A and B. How to do this using network simulation/throttling tools ?

Comment: iptables might have throttling ability. I never used it, but worth looking into.

Comment: @MichaelMartinez No it doesn't. [`tc`](http://lartc.org/manpages/tc.txt) does when used with iptables marking.

Comment: @XavierLucas good to know!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To do this you can make usage of [`tc`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tc) alone with [`u32`](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.adv-filter.html#LARTC.ADV-FILTER.U32) filters or combined with [iptables marking](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbAL) (maybe more straightforward if you don't want to learn the complex filters syntax). I'll in the following post detail the former solution.

## Simulating your setup

As an example, let's consider A, B, C and D running  **10 Mbit/s** virtual interfaces.

You basically want :

- A <==> B : **9 Mbit/s** shaping for egress
- A <==> C : **8 Mbit/s** shaping for egress

In order to simulate this I'll create 4 network namespaces and virtual ethernet interfaces plugged into a bridge.

Of course, in your case you will work with real NICs and the bridge will be your gateway or a switch depending on your infrastructure.

So in my simulation we will have the following setup, in a 10.0.0.0/24 network :

```
                                  10.0.0.254            

                                  +-------+                     
                                  |       |                     
                                  |  br0  |                     
                                  |       |                   
                                  +---+---+                     
                                      |                         
                                      | veth{A..D}.peer        
                                      |                      
                  +------------+------+-----+------------+     
                  |            |            |            |      
            vethA |      vethB |      vethC |      vethD |      
              +---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+  
              |       |    |       |    |       |    |       |   
              |   A   |    |   B   |    |   C   |    |   D   |   
              |       |    |       |    |       |    |       |  
              +-------+    +-------+    +-------+    +-------+    

              10.0.0.1      10.0.0.2     10.0.0.3     10.0.0.4
```

First, the setup phasis so you can understand what it's made of, skip it if you are unfamiliar with it, no big deal. What you must however know is that the command `ip netns exec <namespace> <command>` allows to execute a command in a network namespace (i.e. in one of the box of the previous draw). This will be used in the next section too.

```
# Create the bridge
ip link add br0 type bridge

# Create network namespaces and veth interfaces and plug them into the bridge
for host in {A..D} ; do 
    ip link netns add ${host}
    ip link add veth${host} type veth peer name veth${host}.peer
    ip link set dev veth${host}.peer master br0
    ip link set dev veth${host} netns ${host}
    ip netns exec ${host} ip link set veth${host} up
done

# Assign IPs
ip addr add 10.0.0.254/24 dev br0
ip netns exec A ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev vethA
ip netns exec B ip addr add 10.0.0.2/24 dev vethB
ip netns exec C ip addr add 10.0.0.3/24 dev vethC
ip netns exec D ip addr add 10.0.0.4/24 dev vethD
```

So at this point we have the setup described previously.

## Shaping traffic

It's time to get into traffic control in order to get what you want. The `tc` tool allows you to add queueing disciplines :

- For egress : once the kernel needs to send packets and before accessing the NIC driver.
- For ingress : after accessing the NIC driver and before the kernel routines are run over the packets received.

It comes with 3 notions : *qdisc*, *classes* and *filters*. Those notions can be used to setup complex packet flow management and priorize traffic based on whatever criterion/criteria you want.

In a nutshell :

- Qdiscs are structures where packets will enventually be enqueued/dequeued.
- Classes are containers for qdiscs acting with specific behaviours.
- Filters are ways to route packets between classes, multiple of them can be defined on the same entry point with priorities during processing.

All these usually work as a tree where leaves are qdiscs and classes are nodes. The root of a tree or subtree will be declared as `<id>:` and children nodes will be declared as `<parent_id>:<children_id>`. Keep this syntax in mind.

For your case, let's take A and render the tree you would like to set up with `tc` :

```
                                     1:
                                      |
                                      |
                                      |
                                     1:1
                                   /  |  \
                                  /   |   \
                                 /    |    \
                               1:10  1:20  1:30
                                |     |     |
                                |     |     |
                               :10   :20   :30
```

Explanation :

- `1:` is the root qdisc attached to the device vethA, it will be taken explicitely as `htb` for Hierarchy Token Bucket (the default qdisc of a device is `pfifo` or `pfifo_fast` depending on the OS). It's specifically appropriate for bandwith management. Packets not matched by filters defined at this level will go to `1:30` class.
- `1:1` will be a `htb` class limiting the whole traffic of the device to 10 Mbit/s.
- `1:10` will be a `htb` class limiting output traffic to 9 Mbit/s (90% of 10 Mbit/s).
- `1:20` will be a `htb` class limiting output traffic to 8 Mbit/s (80% of 10 Mbit/s).
- `1:30` will be a `htb` class limiting traffic to 10 Mbit/s (fallback).
- `:10, :20, :30` are `sfq` qdisc for Stochastic Fairness Queueing. In other words these qdiscs will ensure fairness in transmission schedluding based on flows.

This whole thing is setup by the following commands :

```
ip netns exec A tc qdisc add dev vethA root handle 1: htb default 30
ip netns exec A tc class add dev vethA parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 10mbit burst 15k
ip netns exec A tc class add dev vethA parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 9mbit burst 15k
ip netns exec A tc class add dev vethA parent 1:1 classid 1:20 htb rate 8mbit burst 15k
ip netns exec A tc class add dev vethA parent 1:1 classid 1:30 htb rate 10mbit burst 15k
ip netns exec A tc qdsic add dev vethA parent 1:10 handle 10: sfq perturb 10
ip netns exec A tc qdisc add dev vethA parent 1:20 handle 20: sfq perturb 10
ip netns exec A tc qdisc add dev vethA parent 1:30 handle 30: sfq perturb 10
```

The last thing we need is adding filters so IP packets with destination IP equals B will go to `1:10` class and IP packets with destination IP equals C will go to `1:20` class :

```
ip netns exec A tc filter add dev vethA parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip dst 10.0.0.2/32 flowid 1:10
ip netns exec A tc filter add dev vethA parent 1: protocol ip prio 2 u32 match ip dst 10.0.0.3/32 flowid 1:20
```

Now that you get the idea, you will need to add similar `tc` rules to B and C so transmissions towards A from these rigs are also shaped.

## Testing

Now let's test it. For this I'm personnally used to play with `iperf`, it simply consists of a single binary that can be either run as a client or a server and will automatically send as much traffic as possible between both hosts.

Between A and B :

```
 $ ip netns exec B iperf -s -p 8001
  ...
 $ ip netns exec A iperf -c 10.0.0.2 -p 8001 -t 10 -i 2
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 10.0.0.2, TCP port 8001
TCP window size: 21.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  5] local 10.0.0.1 port 58191 connected with 10.0.0.2 port 8001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]  0.0- 2.0 sec  2.38 MBytes  9.96 Mbits/sec
[  5]  2.0- 4.0 sec  2.12 MBytes  8.91 Mbits/sec
[  5]  4.0- 6.0 sec  2.00 MBytes  8.39 Mbits/sec
[  5]  6.0- 8.0 sec  2.12 MBytes  8.91 Mbits/sec
[  5]  8.0-10.0 sec  2.00 MBytes  8.39 Mbits/sec
[  5]  0.0-10.1 sec  10.8 MBytes  8.91 Mbits/sec
```

We get our **9 Mbit/s** bandwith limit.

Between A and C :

```
$ ip netns exec C iperf -s -p 8001
...
$ ip netns exec A iperf -c 10.0.0.3 -p 8001 -t 10 -i 2
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 10.0.0.3, TCP port 8001
TCP window size: 21.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  5] local 10.0.0.1 port 58522 connected with 10.0.0.3 port 8001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]  0.0- 2.0 sec  2.25 MBytes  9.44 Mbits/sec
[  5]  2.0- 4.0 sec  1.75 MBytes  7.34 Mbits/sec
[  5]  4.0- 6.0 sec  1.88 MBytes  7.86 Mbits/sec
[  5]  6.0- 8.0 sec  1.88 MBytes  7.86 Mbits/sec
[  5]  8.0-10.0 sec  1.75 MBytes  7.34 Mbits/sec
[  5]  0.0-10.1 sec  9.62 MBytes  7.98 Mbits/sec
```

We get our **8 Mbit/s** bandwith limit.

Between A and D :

```
$ ip netns exec D iperf -s -p 8001
...
$ ip netns exec A iperf -c 10.0.0.4 -p 8001 -t 10 -i 2
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 10.0.0.4, TCP port 8001
TCP window size: 21.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  5] local 10.0.0.1 port 40614 connected with 10.0.0.4 port 8001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]  0.0- 2.0 sec  2.62 MBytes  11.0 Mbits/sec
[  5]  2.0- 4.0 sec  2.25 MBytes  9.44 Mbits/sec
[  5]  4.0- 6.0 sec  2.38 MBytes  9.96 Mbits/sec
[  5]  6.0- 8.0 sec  2.25 MBytes  9.44 Mbits/sec
[  5]  8.0-10.0 sec  2.38 MBytes  9.96 Mbits/sec
[  5]  0.0-10.2 sec  12.0 MBytes  9.89 Mbits/sec
```

Here we have the virtual interface full speed of **10 Mbit/s** reached.

Note that the burst of the first measure of each run can be better handled in `htb` classes by adjusting the adequate parameter.

## Cleaning up

To remove :

- The filter of priority 1 on `1:` : `tc filter del dev vethA parent 1: prio 1 u32`.
- All filters on `1:` : `tc filter del dev vethA parent 1:`.
- Class `1:20` and its children : `tc class del dev vethA parent 1:1 classid 
  1:20`.
- The whole tree : `tc qdisc del dev vethA`.

To clean up the simulation set :

```
# Remove veth pairs and network namespaces
for host in {A..D} ; do
    ip link del dev veth${host}.peer
    ip netns del ${host}
done

# Remove the bridge
ip link del dev br0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your amazing reply. If possible, could you please add the commands to remove the filters ? just in case anyone wants to rollback this setup safely after the simulation.

Comment: @YahiaZakaria I just added this information in the latter part of my post.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu have IPFW ported from FreeBSD, and IPFW have DUMMYNET that allow to manage various network parameters - bandwidth, delay, rate of packet loss, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use the tc tools with the now integrated (in Ubuntu server at least) netem module. You can find more info in [this article from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614795/simulate-delayed-and-dropped-packets-on-linux).

Comment: Netem is about rtt and congestion emulation, not about bandwith.

Comment: @XavierLucas, you are right, for bandwidth you just need tc, without even netem.

Answer (score 0):

Trickle works well.

This discussion shows some limitations:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109973/how-to-change-speed-limit-of-running-trickle-instance

Comment: Trickle is used to simulate the network bandwith for a specific program. The OP seems to seek a solution at host's scope.

Comment: Trickled can be used to simulate a group of connections (not just a single connection).  Indeed the question could be interpreted as "all connections host-to-host".